# Unable to run debug build of application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, winsxs

Visual Studio 2005, SP1 with Vista/Win7 update.  The PC originally had VS 2010 installed but, since the rest of the team uses 2005, well, when in Rome...

Initially, I installed 2005 and the updates and tried to build/run.  Build ran fine, running (in debug mode) failed.  So I uninstalled the VS updates, removed all versions of VS and associated components and reinstalled VS2005 with the SP and Win7 update.

Same issue running in debug mode.  I get a dialog telling me that the application config is incorrect.  A check of the event log shows:

```
Activation context generation failed for "u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\ESM_Win32_App.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis
```

And running sxstrace gives me:

```
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\ESM_Win32_App.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\ESM_Win32_App.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_6d78e2ee5a7eb616.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50608.0__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui\8.0.50727.762_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at u:\ESM\ESM_Layer\debug\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT, the manifest file there contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <noInheritable></noInheritable>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    <file name="msvcr80d.dll" hash="9062fecdbc9ab7df4d66e81b37e9cecdee037430" hashalg="SHA1"><asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod><dsig:DigestValue>g5HUX4P7M3mkZuWgfND7EdkmVgs=</dsig:DigestValue></asmv2:hash></file>
    <file name="msvcp80d.dll" hash="cf233a4bb28335cd6b4f62b5947d119faefa5bcb" hashalg="SHA1"><asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod><dsig:DigestValue>lGYgPP6K9l5G0HBKTJ/Rlj2Vybg=</dsig:DigestValue></asmv2:hash></file>
    <file name="msvcm80d.dll" hash="47021cd154192d51aad190daed426bf47156fa40" hashalg="SHA1"><asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod><dsig:DigestValue>1fLI6D1TNH6Hwc1D/toIuhn/R+4=</dsig:DigestValue></asmv2:hash></file>
</assembly>
```

If I go to my Debug (output) directory for the application, there is a file (ESM_Win32_App.exe.embed.manifest) which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50608.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.6195" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

My c:\windows\winsxs dir contains:

> x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.1833_none_d08b763a442c70c2
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4027_none_d08a21a2442db2dc
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d08d7da0442a985d
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_db5f52fb98cb24ad
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_10b2f55f9bffb8f8
>
> x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_ef74ff32550b5bf0
>   x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b

Seems there are more runtime flavours of the DLLs than Debug, but, I don't even appear to have a runtime version of the 6195 DLLs, let alone Debug.

My c:\windows\assembly\gac_32 does not contain a dir named Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT, which the output of sxstrace seems to suggest should exist.

So, I gather that a certain set of Debug DLLs are not being found, or are not installed, but I am at a loss as to how to resolve this.  One fellow does not have this issue and another does.  Neither have any thoughts.  Visual Studio seems to have .762 installed, which I would have thought would have been upgraded by SP1 and/or the Vista update... but I don't know where they'd be if that was the case, I just know they're not where I thought they'd be.  Maybe I need to install another update?  I also find it puzzling that my VS is trying to use .6195 of the DLLs but, where would it get that information - might it obtain that from other DLLs (ie: those that might come from other groups?) and thus try to use whatever it thinks is the most recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.  Installed the following updates (gleaned by looking at a colleagues PC): KB2251481, KB2538218, KB2548826 and KB973673.  I don't know specifically which one updated the DLLs to the required version but this combination did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to Jon's own answer, but my account is new and I don't have enough reputation to add a comment or upvote his answer. I just wanted to confirm that his answer worked:

Thanks Jon. I was receiving the same error about missing version 8.0.50727.6195 of Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT when trying to run my debug compilation on a new install of Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2005. Following your comments, I ran Windows Update, and the problem was resolved. This included all 4 updates mentioned, so I don't know which one helped.

Comment: you can comment once you have enough rep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its KB2538218 that has the 6195 debug crt libs. Thank you for the info!